# What does it mean that a variogram keeps increasing with distance?

Tags: normal-distribution, autocorrelation, spatial, gaussian-process, variogram

I am modeling my 3D dataset with a Gaussian Process with square-exponential covariance. To test whether this is a good model, I subtract the mean from the observed data and then calculate the empirical variogram:

$$
\gamma(d) = \frac{1}{2|N(d)|}\sum_{i,j\in N(d)}|z_i - z_j|^2
$$

Where $N(d)$ is the set of pairs at distance $d$. I compared it against the theoretical variogram:

$$
\gamma(d) = \frac{1}{(2\pi\sigma^2)^{3/2}}\left[1.0 - exp\left(-\frac{d^2}{ 2\sigma^2}\right)\right]
$$

However when I plot it I get this weird effect where the variogram is low and slowly increases without end. Any idea what's going on? At first I thought the mean was incorrect, but when I change it the whole observed plot just shifts up and down, keeping that slow increase.

[image: variogram]

Comment: Any trend contributes its *square* (additively) to a variogram: see http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/35524/919. It's also possible for the random field to be "intrinsic": variograms *can* increase without bound.  The simplest example is a random walk whose variogram is linear. 3D variography is complicated. In particular, it must be guided by theoretical and statistical understanding of the underlying phenomenon; you can't do it well by treating the numbers abstractly. Consider first getting more experience by studying textbooks and papers that give extended case studies in 2D variography.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You likely have a trend in you data. So as locations get further apart the variance increases. Try to detrend the data and then do again.